# "Of all the boys I've known, until I first met you I was lonesome" - what does the "of" mean?

Tags: word-usage

The swing classic "Bei mir bist du schön" starts with the lines

> Of all the boys I've known
> And I've known some
> Until I first met you
> I was lonesome.

One can gather the intended meaning, but what kind of use of "of" is this exactly? Is an "In spite" missing in the beginning?

https://genius.com/The-andrews-sisters-bei-mir-bist-du-schon-lyrics

Comment: By the way, those weren't the song's *original* lyrics, because it started as a hit from Yiddish theater (and a Germanized version was a hit in Nazi Germany until they learned its origins). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bei_Mir_Bistu_Shein

Answer (score 2):

It's not actually grammatical here, but songs often are not. In expressions such as 'of all the boys I've known', 'of all the cars I've owned', 'of all the places I've been', etc, one can consider 'of' to mean 'out of', or 'among', but they should be followed by something about the thing mentioned, such as 'you're the handsomest', 'this Ford is the worst', or 'Paris is the most beautiful'.